# How do i have my webpart detect whether it is hosted in Sharepoint or vanilla ASP .Net?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a suite of webpart controls that I maintain and develop for our main Sharepoint offerings. I also have an Asp .Net website which acts as a test suite for selenium scripts and unit tests.

How can I determine from the web part code server code whether the control is currently being hosted in a Sharepoint page or whether the webpart is being hosted on a normal ASP .Net page? I'm looking to prepopulate some of the webpart properties with defaults but only when they exist in the ASP .Net page environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if (this.WebPartManager.GetType().Name == "SPWebPartManager")
    {
    // SharePoint
    }
    else
    {
    // Not SharePoint
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can probably test SPContext.Current.Web to be null

Comment: That's a good suggestion as well. I've went with Per's answer though.